# Reading all file contents from a directory - php

Tags: php, file, directory

This is actually is an easy task

I want to display contents of all files located in specified folder.

I am passing directory name

```
echo "<a href='see.php?qname=". $_name ."'>" . $row["qname"] . "</a>";
```

on second page ,

I am iterating over the directory content

```
while($entryname = readdir($myDirectory)) 
{
            if(is_dir($entryname))
            {
                continue;
            }   
            if($entryname=="." || $entryname==".." )
            {}
            else
            {
                if(!is_dir($entryname))
                {   
                    $fileHandle=fopen($entryname, "r");
                    
                    while (!feof($fileHandle) ) {
           $line = fgets($fileHandle);
           echo $line . "<br />";
        }
```

.
.
.

but I am unable to read any file , I have changed their permissions as well.

I tried putting directory name statically which worked,
Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$entryname` will contain JUST the filename, with no path information. You have to manually rebuild the path yourself. e.g.

```
$dh = opendir('/path/you/want/to/read/');
while($file = readdir($dh)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents('/path/you/want/to/read/' . $file);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---include path here
}
```

Without the explicit path in your "read the file code", you're trying to open and read a file in the script's current working directory, not the director you're reading the filenames from.

Comment: I'd recommend adding something like

    `if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }`

right after the while on linux servers

Answer (score 5):

Much simpler:

```
foreach(glob("$myDirectory/*") as $file) {
    foreach(file($file) as $line) {
        echo $line . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Even simpler:

```
foreach(glob("$myDirectory/*") as $file) {
    echo nl2br(file_get_contents($file));
}
```