# How to compute tf-idf from multiple text files in php?

Tags: php, tf-idf

I'm successfully computing tf-idf from an array. Now I want that tf-idf should be computed from multiple text files as I have multiple text files in my directory. Can anyone please modify this code for multiple text files so that first all the files in the directory should read and then on the basis of these files contents tf-idf computed.. Below is my code thanks...

```
$collection = array(
    1 => 'this string is a short string but a good string',
    2 => 'this one isn\'t quite like the rest but is here',
    3 => 'this is a different short string that\' not as short'
);

$dictionary = array();
$docCount = array();

foreach($collection as $docID => $doc) {
    $terms = explode(' ', $doc);
    $docCount[$docID] = count($terms);

    foreach($terms as $term) {
        if(!isset($dictionary[$term])) {
            $dictionary[$term] = array('df' => 0, 'postings' => array());
        }
        if(!isset($dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID])) {
            $dictionary[$term]['df']++;
            $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID] = array('tf' => 0);
        }

        $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID]['tf']++;
    }
}

$temp = ('docCount' => $docCount, 'dictionary' => $dictionary);
```

**Computing tf-idf**

```
$index = $temp;
$docCount = count($index['docCount']);
$entry = $index['dictionary'][$term];
foreach($entry['postings'] as  $docID => $postings) {
    echo "Document $docID and term $term give TFIDF: " .
        ($postings['tf'] * log($docCount / $entry['df'], 2));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: We are not on codingserverviceoverflow ... please try by yourself and come when you stuck

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this answer: [Reading all file contents from a directory - php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982865/4375900)
There you find the information how to read all the file contents from a directory.
With this information you should be able to modify your code by yourselve to get it work like expected.